# x86_64 running in Long mode 64-bit submode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-architecture, osdev

I would ask a clarification on how an x86_64 processor knows it is in IA-32e 64 bit submode.

As far as I known, the `LM`-bit inside `EFER MSR` (`0xC0000080`) must be set. Furthermore the `L` bit in the current code segment descriptor (currently cached in the `CS` descriptor cache) must be set (1).

Are there any other pieces that need to be configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Intel 10.8.5 *"Initializing IA-32e Mode"* section:

> On Intel 64 processors, the IA32_EFER MSR is cleared on system reset.
> The operating system must be in protected mode with paging enabled
> before attempting  to initialize IA-32e mode. IA-32e mode operation
> also requires physical-address extensions  with four or five levels of
> enhanced paging structures (see Section 4.5, “4-Level Paging and
> 5-Level Paging”).
>
> Operating systems should follow this sequence to initialize IA-32e
> mode:
>
> 1. Starting from protected mode, disable paging by setting CR0.PG = 0. Use the MOV CR0 instruction to disable
>    paging (the instruction must be located in an identity-mapped page).
> 2. Enable physical-address extensions (PAE) by setting CR4.PAE = 1. Failure to enable PAE will result in a #GP
>    fault when an attempt is made to initialize IA-32e mode.
> 3. Load CR3 with the physical base address of the Level 4 page map table (PML4) or Level 5 page map table
>    (PML5).
> 4. Enable IA-32e mode by setting IA32_EFER.LME = 1.
> 5. Enable paging by setting CR0.PG = 1. This causes the processor to set the IA32_EFER.LMA bit to 1. The MOV
>    CR0 instruction that enables paging and the following instructions must be located in an identity-mapped page
>    (until such time that a branch to non-identity mapped pages can be effected).

So, you first need to prepare *4/5-level page tables*, next you must enable PAE (Physical Address Extension) and only then enable LME bit. Once you enabled LME bit you can enable *paging* (if you enable it before you set LME bit the processor will think you use 32-bit paging, i.e. 2/3-level page tables and produce incorrect translation).

This picture is the illustration of how paging mode transitions work:
[image]

Right after switching to IA-32e 64-bit submode you must reload system data structures (GDT, IDT, TSS, etc.). Especially to be able to jump onto 64-bit code you must turn on `L` bit for GDT code descriptors. After reloading all those structures you can do your work as usual in 64-bit mode.

Comment: So from protected mode, when all points 1-5 in the list are done, the processor actually enters in IA-32e 64-bit submode by a far jump to a code segment with `L` bit set in the corresponding GDT entry.

Comment: correct, once you entered 64-bit mode you continue using old GDT (from protected mode), so to be able to execute 64-bit instructions you should reload it (use 64-bit version), and after that to reload `CS` you use far jump where you usually reload remain segment selectors (`DS`, `SS`, `ES`, etc.)

Comment: Other point: _the instruction must be located in an identity-mapped page_ does mean that the protected mode's paging structure has to map the addresses of the virtual page in which the MOV CR0 instruction is located to a physical page withe the same (physical) address

Comment: Yes, that is what identity-paging means (see https://wiki.osdev.org/Identity_Paging)

Comment: Sorry, about the reloading of GDT when entering in 64 bit mode: a new version of GDT is actually needed or we can just employ different entries of the same old in-memory GDT (from protected mode) ?

Comment: You should reload GDTR first, because it is different in 64-bit mode. Then you can modify current code segment descriptor (you can do that, because segment selectors are cached in `CS`, `DS`, `SS`, etc., so you will continue using old values from `CS`, `DS`, etc., also note that in 64-bit mode `ES`, `DS` and `SS` are not used, moreover instructions like `LDS` will generate exception) and reload it using  far jump

Comment: Ah ok, so you can safely update the in-memory GDT's current code segment descriptor and then do a far jump to implicitly reload it into `CS` register (inclusive of the hidden part).

Comment: @CarloC: Safely as long as you've disabled interrupts.  The segment register internals are not a cache, per-se, like they can never reload from memory on their own.  They're just machine state that's set when you do a far jump or an interrupt happens.

Comment: @PeterCordes you mean that if OS rewrites the in-memory GDT descriptor then the segment register hidden part/descriptor cache is not automatically updated accordingly.

Comment: @CarloC: Right.  It's not a cache, it's not coherent with stores to memory.

Comment: @PeterCordes: another point: Linux 64-bit does not setup at all any `GDT` descriptor entry to be loaded into `FS` or `GS` segment register, right ? Their base addresses (inside their associated descriptor caches) are configured writing the associated `MSRs` or via `wrfsbase` or `wrgsbase` even from userspace.

Comment: @CarloC: Right. Even in a 32-bit user-space process (under a 64-bit kernel), FS=GS=0, the null selector which doesn't load a GDT or LDT entry. I checked with GDB.  (Why did you repost this comment I'd already replied to?)

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry, just my fault :-)